# I am unable to upload file to my local host folder in php

Tags: file-upload, php

I have the follwing code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>  

<?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

my page is in http://local.host/nausal/upload.php

now I am having the follwing error though i have created a folder in site with name upload.

> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded in C:\wamp\www\Nausal\upload.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded in C:\wamp\www\Nausal\upload.php on line 17
> Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

Comment: Did you actually upload any files using this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is a part of upload.php too, you need to encapsulate the PHP-code and first check if $_FILES is not empty, otherwise you will always get a Notice if you only want to display the form.

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
        //your PHP-code here
  }
?>
<!-- your form here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

- Khan sb Place this code in file
  called upload.php
- create a folder called upload where
  you created upload.php
- change `echo "The file ". basename(
  $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). "
  has been uploaded";` to `echo "The
  file ". basename(
  $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has
  been uploaded";`

This will upload file successfully. First time when upload.php is uploaded there is no file selected so you will see some errors. But after you select a file and click upload you will not see any error. To avoid this error do as suggested by Dr. Molle

Comment: how will now display this image on another page named show.php

Comment: @Nouman Write another question for that. You can use img tag with path of this image. After this image has uploaded successfully you can save file path in session. Google "How to show image in php "How to store sessions in PHP"